# Is Cronbach's alpha interchangeable with $\rho$?

Tags: correlation, reliability, cronbachs-alpha

I am trying to calculate the reliability of my change scores using the following formula.  Is $r$ ($\rho$) in this instance interchangeable with Cronbach's alpha? 
$$
\frac{.5(r_{xx}+ r_{yy}) - r_{xy}}{1 - r_{xy}}
$$
Where reliability of difference scores is a function of the score reliability of each measure ($r_{xx}, r_{yy}$) and the correlation between the measures ($r_{xy}$).

Comment: Hello - I think you are or should be asking whether just the first 2 of the r expressions in the equation can be replaced by Cronbach's alpha.  The last 2, which are pre-post correlations, should not.  Or then again, maybe you mean the entire equation produces an equivalent of alpha?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, just the rxx and the ryy.  Can these be replaced with Cronbach's alpha?

Comment: I think Yes, as long as you have unidimensional scales so that alpha will be an applicable indicator.